# DolphinDB reactive state engine: Calculate the metrics of the last 10 records in a column

Tags: state, streaming, dolphindb

When processing stream data with the reactive state engine,  I want to count how many of the last ten rows have the same value as the current row. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a user-defined function combined with the `moving` function.

(1) Define an aggregate function

```
defg ncount(x){
    return sum(x == x.tail())
}
```

(2) Function ncount() is defined within function `moving`.

It is used as the formula in parameter *mertic*.

```
metrics =[<time>, <moving(ncount, price, 10)>]
```